# Platform invocation services for .NET

Tags: .net, dll, pinvoke

Is there any better way to load and use functions from a DLL file in .NET (C#) than by using so-called [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services)?

If the DLL file contains functions that were written using JNI is there still a way to use them in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For native DLLs your options are P/invoke or COM. The latter is easier once you have got over the not insignificant hurdle of making a COM server.

Comment: what about JNI? is it possible to somehow use JNI code in .NET?