# How to use C functions from dll in .net(C#)?

Tags: .net, dll, types, multilingual

If there's a dll written on **C**, then how is it possible to use it in .net(C#)?

Is it strictly necessary to write a header file for it in order to data types be compatible between two languages?

Comment: No offense, because it might not be obvious, but you might want to check (and accept?!?) the answer to your similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224444/platform-invocation-services-for-net.

Comment: P/invoke or COM are still your 2 options

Comment: header file is irrelevant since c# doesn't use header files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know about P/invoke from your previous question. Regarding the header file, it's not used for managed interop. Instead the P/invoke declarations specify the function parameters, calling conventions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  It's called unmanaged DLL. 
There are quite a few tutorials in this regards. 
One of them i had from before when i was working in this similar aspect is:
[1] http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx